# malloc on (char**)

Tags: c, malloc, exec, posix, fork

Well, I'm trying to write a shell for linux using C. Using the functions fork() and execl(), I can execute each command, but now I'm stuck trying to read the arguments:

```
char * command;
char ** c_args = NULL;

bytes_read = getline (&command, &nbytes, stdin);

command = strtok(command, "\n ");
int arg = 0;
c_arg = strtok(NULL, "\n ");
while( c_arg != NULL ) {
    if( c_args == NULL ) {
        c_args = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    }
    else {
        c_args = (char**) realloc( c_args, sizeof(char*) * (arg + 1) );
    }
    c_args[arg] = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char)*1024 );
    strcpy( c_args[arg], c_arg );
    c_arg = strtok(NULL, "\n ");
    arg++;
}
...
pid_t pid = fork()
...
...
execl( <path>, command, c_args, NULL)
...
...
```

That way I get errors from the command when I try to pass arguments, for example:

```
ls -l
```

Gives me:

```
ls: cannot access p��: No such file or directory
```

I know that the problem is the c_args allocation. What's wrong with it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `execl()` for a variable list of arguments; you need to use `execv()` or one of its variants (`execve()`, `execvp()`, etc).  You can only use `execl()` when you know all the arguments that will be present at compile time.  In most cases, a general shell won't know that.  An exception is when you do something like:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", command_line, (char *)0);
```

Here, you're invoking the shell to run a single string as the command line (with no other arguments).  However, when you're dealing with what people type at the keyboard in a full shell, you won't have the luxury of knowing how many arguments they typed at compile time.

At its simplest, you should be using:

```
execvp(c_args[0], c_args);
```

The zeroth argument, the command name, should be what you pass to `execvp()`.  If that's a simple file name (no `/`), then it will look for the command in directories on your `$PATH` environment variable.  If the command name contains a slash, then it will look for the (relative or absolute) file name specified and execute that if it exists, and fail if it does not.  The other arguments should all be in the null-terminated list `c_args`.

Now, there may also be other memory allocation issues; I've not scrutinized the code.  You could check them, though, by diagnostic printing of the argument list:

```
char **pargs = c_args;
while (*pargs != 0)
    puts(*pargs++);
```

That prints each argument on a separate line.  Note that it doesn't stop until it encounters a null pointer; it is crucial that you null terminate your list of pointers to the argument strings.

This bit of your code:

```
c_args[arg] = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char)*1024 );
strcpy( c_args[arg], c_arg );
```

looks like overkill in the usual case, and an inadequate memory allocation in the extreme cases.  When you're copying strings around, allocate enough length.  I see that you're using `strtok()` to bust apart a string — it'll do for the early incarnations of a shell, but when you get to process command lines like `ls -l>$tmp`, you will find `strtok()`'s penchant for trampling over your delimiter before you get to read it becomes a major liability.  However, while you're using it, you probably don't have to copy the arguments like that; you can just set `c_args[arg++] = result_from_strtok;`.  When you do need to copy, you should probably use `strdup()`; it doesn't forget to allocate enough space for the trailing `'\0'`, for example, and neither over-allocates nor under-allocates.

Comment: This is the kind of answers I love, thank you so much. You not only answered my question, you made me learn a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan has a great answer, I just wanted to add a few more things.

You *could* use `popen` or `system` to just execute by the shell directly. They are usually frowned upon since they can be injected so easily, but if you are writing an open shell, I don't see the harm in using them.

If you are going for a limited shell (which accepts a sh-like syntax), take a look into [wordexp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp). It does a lot, but in my experience it does too much, especially if you are trying to write a moderately secure interpreter (it does silly things like tilde expansion and variable substitution).

Comment: Yeah, I know about system, but is not a good production-function from what I know.